# How to set a custom Key for files uploaded to appengine using blobstore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

Following the [appengine Uploading a blob instructions](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/), I have been available to upload/download images.

But I want to found a method for preventing duplicates, therefore I would like to know if it is possible to have a custom key for the **blobstore** objects, or use the **MD5** as the **Key**, so that at least I could overwrite existing files.

Is there any **hook** or some extra parameter that I could use within the `blobstore.create_upload_url` that could help to specify a custom **Key** for the uploaded object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google is moving away from the blobstore. You can also use the Cloudstorage Client Library.

Some of the benefits:

- since 1,9.0 free quota in the default GCS bucket
- use folders and filenames and you can overwrite (replace) existing files.
- create a serving_url for images and other files, which will be served by Google
- and more ..

I have created [this gist](https://gist.github.com/voscausa/9541133) to show how to use [GCS in Google App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/).

Answer (score 1):

Blob keys are guaranteed to be unique. You don't need to do anything for that.

EDIT:

If you want to rewrite the blob, you need to know the key of a blob that you want to update somewhere in your model. If you want, you can also store a hash or any other identifier (i.e.  file name) in your model too. Then you can compare a hash of a new file, for example, with the hashes of previously stored files, and decide if you want to delete a duplicate record.

Comment: How can I change the behaviour so that I can have my own **Keys**?, for example if I use the **md5** as key, I could upload the same file multiple times, but at the end will have only one record instead of many records with the same data. Any ideas?

Comment: You cannot change this behavior. You need to remember the key of a blob that you want to rewrite/delete. I updated my answer.